# "I think you could help me" or "I thought you could help me" on the essay?

Tags: tenses

1. I think you could help me on the essay.
2. I thought you could help me on the essay.

Which one is correct?
Sense is, one is asking other, maybe you could help me on the essay

I was talking to my friend online regarding essay submission, at that moment I wrote, I think you could help me on the essay,

Comment: They're both grammatical, one is in the present tense, the other is in the past tense.

Comment: Do you currently think this (the first sentence), or did you think it in the past but no longer do, or you're specifically talking about what you were thinking at a moment in the past without regard to how you think now (the second sentence)?  Also, it would be more common to say "with the essay" here.

Comment: 1. You are asking for help. 2. You were refused help.

Comment: @WeatherVane That doesn't seem quite correct. **Counterexamples**: 1. I think you could help me on the essay if you weren't already helping Bob. (I'm not asking for help, I'm stating that you are **hypothetically capable** of helping) 2. I decided to visit you because I thought you could help me with my essay (**I haven't been refused help**; even though the thought occurred in the past, I currently still have that thought)

Comment: @Flater quite right, it is not limited to my examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The First Sentence (Sentence 1):

"I think you could help me on the essay." is grammatically correct, but has a slightly different meaning than what you might expect. You used the present tense for "think", and past/[conditional-mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood) tense for "can", as detailed in [A classic question: can vs. could](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41655/a-classic-question-can-vs-could)

Your sentence means: I currently believe that you are probably able to help me on the essay.

If you are certain that your friend can help you out, you could instead say: "I think you **can** help me on the essay."

### The Second Sentence (Sentence 2):

"I thought you could help me on the essay." is also grammatically correct. (Good Job!)

This sentence means: I believed that you were probably able to help me on the essay.

This implies that your friend cannot currently help you with the essay, and is probably not what you meant. Although, you could flip the meaning of this sentence with a follow up:

"I thought you could help me on the essay, but now I know you can help me on the essay."

Writing like this might seem overly dramatic for your purposes though.

Props to [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth) for simplifying the sentence meaning.

Comment: 'I used to believe that you probably used to be able to help me on the essay.' has the wrong aspect. You want  'I believed that you were probably  able to help me on the essay.'